# Android Oauth 1.0 Authentication with OkHttp

Tags: java, android, oauth, okhttp

I am trying to Authenticate Oauth 1.0 in android.
I send a request with postman and get a response via postman and this program gives me a Java code but it doesn't work.its return 401 error

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

Request request = new Request.Builder()
.url("https://test.com/wp-json/wc/v3/customers? 
oauth_consumer_key=KEY&oauth_token=&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-HA1&oauth_timestamp=1564471240&oauth_nonce=iEo45PESRdt&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=NQR4Xr5OKlb3H+rL0y2PNLdfXpY=")
  .get()
  .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
  .addHeader("User-Agent", "PostmanRuntime/7.15.2")
  .addHeader("Accept", "*/*")
  .addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
  .addHeader("Postman-Token", "6fb2e16e-376c-453a-bf30-18ef6c00020c,c14db88a-55dd-4287-a132-8ca441a5e3f0")
  .addHeader("Host", "test.com")
  .addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate")
  .addHeader("Connection", "keep-alive")
  .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
  .build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

Comment: what is the response u get? does it crash? could you specify more?

Comment: 401 error @Coder123

Comment: and you are 100% sure you pass the same header as in the postman?

Comment: yes I'm sure its return     {"code":"woocommerce_rest_authentication_error","message":"\u0628\u0631\u0686\u0633\u0628 \u0632\u0645\u0627\u0646 \u0646\u0627\u0645\u0639\u062a\u0628\u0631 \u0627\u0633\u062a.","data":{"status":401}}     @Coder123

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the code generated by Postman does not respect the Authentication section.

Go to the Headers section and click "9 hidden" to see the "Authorization" header

[[image: show hidden]]

[[image: see the auth header]]

Comment: This does not offer a solution and should be posted as a comment